# Rails activrecord jobs queue with maximum execution frequency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, job-scheduling

I've ActiveRecord model:

```
User(id,user_specific_attributes, last_check:datetime, check_priority:integer, today_api_calls:integer)
```

I'm doing API call for each `User` once a day. API has some important limits:

- it's accesible from 4am to 8pm
- call frequency limit: 10 per minute = 6 seconds timeout
- call count limit: 3000/day

I need to run `get_some_data_from_api()` for each `User` once a day (start at 4am). Execution order is defined by `check_priority` column.
In case of error from `get_some_data_from_api()` it should restart job after 6 seconds (api limit).

Is there any gem suitable for this case?

Gems like Sidekiq, Delayed Job, Resque are unsuitable. Using them I need to queue all jobs with specific time. Consider:

1. Adding new job with high priority (requeue all next jobs?)
2. Job execution can take more than 6 seconds
3. Restarting job in case of error (requeue all next jobs?)

Answer (score 0):

[Delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) would also work. It has options to run at specific time and reschedule if job fails.

DJ runs as a separate instance of your app. You can assign priorities to jobs. The time of execution does not matter. It has built in options to configure retry on failure.

To schedule jobs at a specific time and to reschedule them, I use self perpetuating jobs. So after the job is done it reschedules itself. Something like

```
def run_me
  ///code code
   User.delayed_job(:run_at => next_day).run_me
end
```

You can handle certain errors in the same way. For eg if api limit is crossed you may want to catch some exception and reschedule next day instead of 6 secs.

Comment: Yes but using DJ I need to queue all jobs with specific time. Consider: 1. Adding new job with high priority (requeue all next jobs?) 2. Job execution can take more than 6 seconds 3. Restarting job in case of error (requeue all next jobs?)